# Can't Use Object Property to Create Color in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI iOS application that's pulling data from a local JSON file.

Everything works properly except, within one view, I am unable to use a property of an object passed into the view to create a new `Color`.

```
struct CategoryItem: View {
    var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: item.backgroundColor[0] / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255))
```

For some reason, the `item.backgroundColor[0]` returns properly if I print it out using `String(item.backgroundColor[0])`, so the value is there, but the calculation is throwing an error. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that `Color` is a computed property, but I'm not sure why the error is occurring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example?  We don't have access to `Item` so it's very hard to say what's happening.

Comment: Which error compiler or run-time? Which `item.backgroundColor[0]` value is there of which type? What is the other code of this `body`? Needs more details, provided snapshot is not testable.

Comment: Thank you, these were helpful in diagnosing the issue! I posted the answer below in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

It turns out that `item.backgroundColor[0]` needs to be specified as a `Double()` even though the static integers (e.g. `255`) are expressed as integers.

The solutions was to wrap everything in `Double()` using a function like this:

```
func colorsFromProperty(colors: [Double]) -> Color {
  return Color(red: Double(colors[0] / 255), green: Double(colors[1] / 255), blue: Double(colors[2] / 255))
}
```